# What are the usecases to trigger certain the response codes for Auth.net?

Tags: authorize.net

I looked on https://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/testing_guide.html
and can trigger error code 2 with just the zip code, but there isn't anything for most of the other error codes...i.e code 3.

Then on here https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/responseCodes.html
with the list at https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/dist/json/responseCodes.json

There isn't any distinction between codes 21-23,25, and 26.

Does anyone know how to trigger response code 3,4,21,22,23,25,or 26?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to trigger those specific errors...but do you *really* need to? Can't you mock responses with those errors for your testing? If you can get and process the other errors codes, these aren't any different.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.